# How to PSQL COPY with PYTHON

Tags: python, postgresql, copy, psql, kubectl

Trying to run a PSQL COPY command using python. I'm able to connect to the right DB in the given kube cluster.

The lose track of the shell once im on postgres. When i exit, i get the following error.
Is there any wrong with the quotes that I'm using in the PSQL command in the os.system call.

```
import os
import subprocess

conn = 'gcloud container clusters get-credentials clusterA --zone us-west --project projectX'
pg = 'kubectl -n DB exec -it postgres -- bash'


if __name__ == '__main__':

   subprocess.call(back_clus_conn, shell=True)
   subprocess.call(pg, shell=True)
   os.system('psql -U postgres -c "\COPY (SELECT * FROM "public"."tableName") TO tableName.csv DELIMITER ',' CSV"')
```

ERROR:

```
 kubeconfig entry generated for clusterA.
 Defaulted container "postgres" out of: postgres, postgres-exporter
 bash-5.0#
 bash-5.0# exit
 exit
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "test.py", line 19, in <module>
 os.system('psql -U postgres -c "\COPY (SELECT * FROM "public"."tableName") TO tableName.csv DELIMITER ',' CSV"')
 TypeError: system() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Comment: It tells you, you give it two arguments instead of one: `'psql -U postgres -c "\COPY (SELECT * FROM "public"."tableName") TO tableName.csv DELIMITER '` is the first and `' CSV"'` is the second...

Answer (score 0):

You can just run the command in the postgres container exec subprocess call, something like this:

```py
import subprocess

conn = 'gcloud container clusters get-credentials clusterA --zone us-west --project projectX'
copy_cmd = 'psql -U postgres -c "\COPY (SELECT * FROM "public"."tableName") TO tableName.csv DELIMITER \',\' CSV"'
pg = f'kubectl -n DB exec -it postgres -- bash -c {copy_cmd}'

if __name__ == '__main__':
   subprocess.call(back_clus_conn, shell=True)
   subprocess.call(pg, shell=True)
```

Comment: invalid syntax on this line `pg = f'kubectl -n DB exec -it postgres -- bash -c {copy_cmd}'
`

Comment: [F-Strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#id37) are a python3 feature. If you are using python2, you can do `'kubectl -n DB exec -it postgres -- bash -c {}'.format(copy_cmd)`

Answer (score 0):

Based on [sticky bit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9661424/sticky-bit), It tells  you to give it two arguments instead of one.

Currently your code is :

> ```
> os.system('psql -U postgres -c "\COPY (SELECT * FROM "public"."tableName") TO tableName.csv DELIMITER ',' CSV"')
> ```

Add escape characters in the comma `\',\'` between DELIMITER and CSV to be recognizable by Python:

> ```
> os.system('psql -U postgres -c "\COPY (SELECT * FROM "public"."tableName") TO tableName.csv DELIMITER \',\' CSV"')
> ```